# Is there a way to configure cygstart.exe?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

As I understand, `cygstart` associates its argument with the windows standard program set for that case.

But I want to behave my cygwin different than its host in certain cases.

E.g.

```
alias open='cygstart'
open some.pdf
```

should open the pdf with *SumatraPDF* instead of *AcrobatReader*, since it's more usefull to me when I'm working on cygwin.
There is a `--action` option for open to specify a non default behavior, but that's too much typing.

So is there a way to configure open? Maybe by means of a config file or exporting a variable?

**EDIT**

The `--action/-a` doesn't seem to work.

```
$ open --action=sumatraPDF some.pdf 
Unable to start 'some.pdf': There is no application associated with the given file name extension.
```

Comment: Where "too much typing"?? Define your --action in your alias.

Comment: I do not just `open` pdf files, also `open .` or sth other files, so I can't change the alias.

Comment: @mike: Cygstart is for invoking a *registered Windows handler* for non-executable files. If you want to use an alternate program, have you simply tried `<path to program.exe> <path to file to be opened>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** simple enough to create your own `open` shell function that checks the file extension and does something special for .pdf and uses cygstart for everything else. For instance

```
function open
{
    case "$1" in
    *.pdf) sumatraPDF "$1";;
    *) cygstart "$1";;
    esac
}
```

Comment: BTW, this a repost of an answer -- with a blatantly obvious example added -- that was outrageously, unreasonably, and irresponsibly deleted by a moderator. That was the worst moderation call I have ever seen on SO ... it was illiterate, as it misquoted and misrepresented what I wrote. A reasonable response would have been to ask me to enhance my answer by adding an example. How such a person could become a moderator at SO is beyond me. They certainly shouldn't be.